# Tracking Alfresco hits

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, apprequests

I'm pretty new to the Alfresco. Is there any way to track the no.of hits (as in who has been viewing my content) to calculate some kind of Metrics for the portal?

Comment: try elaborating your question more, it seems that you have more information about your problem and you can give better insight to potential collaborators.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, but you could write your own servlet or webscript depending on what you really want to track.

Comment: We would like track the no.of contributions/files uploaded in a site over a fixed period of time. How should i go about to do that?

Comment: For this you don't need something that tracks requests for Alfresco, but you just need to query the Alfresco repository.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Alfresco audit service to see who has accessed what content, number of documents created, etc. In future they are looking to add these kinds of metrics to the interface of Alfresco Enterprise.

So, for now, you're going to have to learn some audit querying:

- http://docs.alfresco.com/4.2/tasks/audit-simple-query.html
- https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Auditing_%28from_V3.4%29

The audit service will return results in JSON that you will have to funnel in to something else for useful representation. We've used D3.js to make graphs with this data in the past.

Alternatively you could look at [google-analytics-tracking](http://share-extras.github.io/addons/google-analytics-tracking/) which integrates Google Analytics and may meet your needs depending on exactly what you need to know.